# Looping through markers in Google Maps API according to length of array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

For this project, I'm pulling data from a database and inputting this data in the Google Maps API script. In this database, I have latitude and longitude values. I am inputting these values in the marker function of Google Maps, and having it loop this function according to the amount of items in the array. Here is the code NOTE: THE LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE VALUES YOU SEE ARE BEING PULLED FROM AN ARRAY IN PHP, I DON'T HAVE THAT CODE LISTED. I MERELY JUST POSTED THE SOURCE CODE FROM THE WEBSITE.

```
var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

var js_lats = ["41.047398","40.736641","40.816628","43.000000"];
var js_longs = ["-73.700974","-74.149620","-74.076141","-70.099998"];
 var js_description = ["Come by and chill out, grab a snack, and watch some Netflix in this cozy dorm room in Big Haus.","Come check out the Red Bulls take on another MLS team!","Come check out the Giants and the Jets at this sports complex!","TEST"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < js_lats.length; i++) {
    //document.write(js_lats.length);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position:new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(js_lats[i]),parseFloat(js_longs[i]))
    });
}
marker.setMap(map);



var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: js_description[0]
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
infowindow.open(map.this);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
infowindow.close();
}); 
infowindow.open(map,marker); 
}
```

As you can see, it is pulling multiple values into the latitude and longitude arrays. And we are looping the marker function according to the amount of items in the array. However, it is not working and only showing one marker on the google map. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: mapProp is not defined.  marker is used out of scope (outside the for loop, you only set the map property of the last marker. (PS - you don't need to yell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript console tells me `mapProp` is not defined. JSHint in jsfiddle tells me `marker is used out of scope` (outside the for loop, you only set the map property of the last marker).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dcs814q/)

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"));

  var js_lats = ["41.047398", "40.736641", "40.816628", "43.000000"];
  var js_longs = ["-73.700974", "-74.149620", "-74.076141", "-70.099998"];
  var js_description = ["Come by and chill out, grab a snack, and watch some Netflix in this cozy dorm room in Big Haus.", "Come check out the Red Bulls take on another MLS team!", "Come check out the Giants and the Jets at this sports complex!", "TEST"];
  var i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < js_lats.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(js_lats[i]), parseFloat(js_longs[i]))
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    marker.setMap(map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: js_description[0]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      infowindow.close();
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```